# How to iterate efficiently when some sub intervals results are known

Tags: php, algorithm, iteration

You have a function that always inputs an interval (natural numbers in this case), this function returns a result, but is quite expensive on the processor, simulated by *sleep* in this example:

```
function calculate($start, $end) {

    $result = 0;

    for($x=$start;$x<=$end;$x++) {
        $result++;
        usleep(250000);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

In order to be more efficient there is an array of old results, that contains the interval used an the result of the function for that interval:

```
$oldResults = [
    ['s'=>1, 'e'=>2, 'r' => 1],
    ['s'=>2, 'e'=>6, 'r' => 4],
    ['s'=>4, 'e'=>7, 'r' => 3]
];
```

If I call `calculate(1,10)` the function should be able to calculate new intervals based on old results and accumulate them, In this particular case it should take the old result from 1 to 2 add that to the old result from 2 to 6 and do a new `calculate(6,10)` and add that too. Take in consideration that the function ignores the old saved interval from 4 to 7 since it was more convenient to use 2-6.

This is a visual representation of the problem: 
[image]

Of course in this example, `calculate()` is quite simple and you can just find particular ways to solve this problem around it, but in the real code `calculate()` is complex and the only thing I know is that `calculate(n0,n3)==calculate(n0,n1)+calculate(n1,n2)+calculate(n2,n3)`.

I cannot find a way to solve the reuse of the old data without using a bunch of IF and foreach, I'm sure there is a more elegant approach to solve this.

You can play with the [code here](http://ideone.com/qNhwVb).

Note: I'm using PHP but I can read JS, Pyton, C and similar languages.

Comment: I really don't get what you want to achive.

Comment: @Jimmmy my mistake, already corrected

Comment: Is the interval `[start, end)` or `[start, end]` (i.e. is `end` included in the interval)? In your formula for `calculate`, it seems to be the first, but in the code it seems to be the second.

Comment: Another question: if the input is an empty interval `[n, n)`, is the result `calculate(n, n)` always `0`?

Comment: What can you tell about the run time of the function? Is it constant? Is it proportional to the interval length?

Comment: In your example, how did you decide that [2-6] would be a better choice than [4-7]? Is it always the longest overall range of a sequence of pre-calculated intervals that is the optimal use?

Answer (score 2):

if you are certain that `calculate(n0,n3)==calculate(n0,n1)+calculate(n1,n2)+calculate(n2,n3)`, then it seems to me that one approach might simply be to establish a database cache.

you can pre-calculate each discrete interval, and store its result in a record.

```
$start = 0;
$end = 1000;

for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i++) {
   $result = calculate($start, $i);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO calculated_cache (start, end, result) VALUES ($start,$i,$result)";
   // execute statement via whatever dbms api
   $start++;
}
```

now whenever new requests come in, a database lookup should be significantly faster. note you may need to tinker with my boundary cases in this rough example.

```
function fetch_calculated_cache($start, $end) {

    $sql = "
      SELECT SUM(result)
      FROM calculated_cache
      WHERE (start BETWEEN $start AND $end)
        AND (end BETWEEN $start AND $end)
    ";

    $result = // whatever dbms api you chose

    return $result;
}
```

there are a couple obvious considerations such as:

- cache invalidation. how often will the results of your `calculate` function change? you'll need to repopulate the database then.
- how many intervals do you want to store? in my example, I arbitrarily picked 1000
- will you ever need to retrieve non-sequential interval results? you'll need to apply the above procedure in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this:

```
 function findFittingFromCache($from, $to, $cache){
    //length for measuring usefulnes of chunk from cache (now 0.1 means 10% percent of total length)
    $totalLength = abs($to - $from);
    $candidates = array_filter($cache, function($val) use ($from, $to, $totalLength){
        $chunkLength = abs($val['e'] - $val['s']);
        if($from <= $val['s'] && $to >= $val['e'] && ($chunkLength/$totalLength > 0.1)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    //sorting to have non-decremental values of $x['s']
    usort($candidates, function($a, $b){ return $a['s'] - $b['s']; });
    $flowCheck = $from;
    $needToCompute = array();
    foreach($candidates as $key => $val){
        if($val['s'] < $flowCheck){
            //already using something with this interval
            unset($candidates[$key]);
        } else {
            if($val['s'] > $flowCheck){
                //save what will be needed to compute
                $needToCompute[] = array('s'=>$flowCheck, 'e'=>$val['s']);
            }
            //increase starting position for next loop
            $flowCheck = $val['e'];
        }
    }
    //rest needs to be computed as well
    if($flowCheck < $to){
        $needToCompute[] = array('s'=>$flowCheck, 'e'=>$to);
    }
    return array("computed"=>$candidates, "missing"=>$needToCompute);
}
```

It is function which returns you two arrays, one "computed" holds found already computed pieces, second "missing" holds gaps between them which must be computed yet.

inside function there is 0.1 threshold, which disqualifies chunks shorter than 10% of total searched length, you can rewrite function to send threshold as parameter, or ommit it completely.

i presume results will be stored and after computing added into cache ($oldResults), which might be of any form (for example database as Jeff Puckett suggested). Do not forget to add all computed chunks and whole seeked length into cache.

I am sorry but i can't find a way without cycles and ifs

Working demo:
[link](https://3v4l.org/kY5VI)